# Combined law of a continuous and a discrete random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent exponential random variables of parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$ respectively. In other words, their density functions are:
$$
f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \\
f_Y(y) = \lambda e^{-\lambda y}
$$
Then we define
$$
U = min (X, Y) \quad V = 1_{U=X}
$$
I want to find the joint law of (U, V). This is what I have got so far.
I want to find $F(u, v) = p(U\leq u, V \leq v)$

**First Case:** $v < 0 \implies p(V \leq v) = 0 \implies F(u, v) = 0$

**Second Case:** $0 \leq v < 1 \implies p (V \leq v) = p (V = 0) = p(X>Y)$
$$
p(X>Y) = \int_0^ \infty \int_0^x \lambda \mu e^{-\lambda x} e^{-\mu y} dy dx = \int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x} (1 - e^{-\mu x})dx = \int _0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x} - \lambda e^{-(\lambda + \mu)x} = 1 - \frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu} = \frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu}
$$
Then, using that $p(A \cap B) = p(A|B)p(B)$:
$$
p(U\leq u, V \leq v) = p(U\leq u|X>Y)p(X>Y) =  \frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu} p(Y\leq u) = \frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu} \int_0^u \mu e^{-\mu y} dy = \frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu} (1-e^{-u\mu}) 
$$
**Third case:** $v \geq 1 \implies p(V \leq v) = 1$. In this case the V random variable is not adding any information
$$
p(U\leq u, V \leq v) = p(U \leq u) = p(X \leq u \cup Y \leq u) =  \\ 
p(X\leq u) + p(Y \leq u) - p(X\leq u \cap Y \leq u) = \\ 
=(1-e^{-u\mu}) + (1-e^{-u\lambda}) - (1-e^{-u\mu})(1-e^{-u\lambda}) = \\
=2 - e^{-u\mu} - e^{-u\lambda} - 1 +e^{-u\lambda}+e^{-u\mu} - e^{-u\mu}e^{-u\lambda} = \\
= 1- e^{-u\mu}e^{-u\lambda}
$$

I do not know if any of this is right. But then I am asked if $U$ and $V$ are independent. I do not know if I am just stuck or I have done something wrong in the previous steps. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance : )

Comment: $V$ is an **indicator function** aka bulb that lights up when $X$ is the smaller of pair $X,Y$. Clearly, knowledge of $V$ tells us the value of $U$. They should be dependent.

Comment: @Quasar They are in fact independent.

Comment: @StubbornAtom yes, i think it does.Thanks a lot!!